# I am trying to resolve a "Dummy Audio," problem

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I am a new Ubuntu user, and I have been trying for a couple of weeks to fix what I now know is a relatively common problem.

My laptop's sound has not worked since I have installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04. The volume control reads as "Dummy Audio."

I have tried to follow the instructions found [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html), and I have had no results.

Most recently, I have determined that my system does have the ability to call-up data confirming the existing of the sound-card, but I don't know how to make it work.

I did so in the following fashion:

I entered the command:

> lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

The result I got was the following:

> 05:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
>
> Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP
>     Audio Controller [1025:134f]
>
> Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>
> Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
>
> 05:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
>   [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2]
>
> Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir
>   Audio Processor [1025:134f]
>
> Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x
>
> 05:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
>       Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1025:134f]
>
> Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>
> Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

If it is any help, my laptop is an Aspire 5.

Comment: The image contained useful information, however as an image it was far less useful than it would have been had you copied the text and added the commands & results into your actual question. That is what I was asking for.